# junit- sonarQube test coverage : if condition

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube

can you help me how I can cover if statement by junit test in this method:

This is my Method in the controller "User" :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/informationUser") 
public ResponseEntity<Utilisateur> getAllInformationAboutUser() {
    Utilisateur user = null; // Fully covered By tests
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); // Fully covered By tests
    if (authentication != null) { // Partially covered by Tests
        user = userService.findUserByLogin(authentication.getName()); // Not covered by Tests
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK); Fully covered By tests
}
```

My problem is with the 2 lines of the if statment, I don't know how i want to cover them.

This is my test code for this method :

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); 
ResponseEntity<Utilisateur> responseEntity16 = userController.getAllInformationAboutUser();
    
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
ResponseEntity<Utilisateur> responseEntity15 = userController.getAllInformationAboutUser();
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Mock the authentication, and make it return an object.

Comment: Before you run this test (2nd time), just `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null)` or `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()`

Comment: @Valijion :  i tried to do that but the line inside the if statment still not covred

Comment: @Maroun : it is the same it is still not covered

Comment: @Valijon i need to make authentication different of null to get full coverage of the method

Comment: You need to run 2 times, where in 1 case it returns not null, and the second one returns null

Comment: @Valijon my problem is that I don't know how I can pass the Authentication variable as not null in the test. Can you help me how can I do this?

Comment: how can I initialisate Authentication with value difference of null  to get cover this line ?

Comment: Can you post please your Test class, so I can help you with the test coverage

Comment: @Valijon i modified my post, you can see khnow how i write the test code.

Comment: Check my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a temporary `Authentication` information

```
@Test
public void getAllInformationAboutUserTest() {
    
    // If you use Mockito -> Mockito.mock(Authentication.class)
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new TestingAuthenticationToken("foo", "bar"));
    ResponseEntity<Utilisateur> responseEntity16 = userController.getAllInformationAboutUser();
        
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    ResponseEntity<Utilisateur> responseEntity15 = userController.getAllInformationAboutUser();
}
```

Result:
[image: Sonar coverage]